# I'm getting error while starting yarn services while hadoop configuration

Tags: xml, hadoop, syntax-error, hadoop-yarn, distributed-computing

Starting yarn daemons,
starting resource manager, logging to `/opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-Web.out`

> [Fatal Error] yarn-site.xml:24:1: The end-tag for element type
>   "property" must end with a '>' delimiter. localhost: starting
>   nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-Web.out
>   localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file named "yarn-site.xml", in line 24, at column 1, you have a syntax error.

You haven't ended a property with `>` as the error message clearly suggests.

---

Taken from [here](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/yarn-site.xml), the general structure for a property is:

```
<property>
 <name> </name>
 <value> </value>
 <description> </description>
</property>
```

It seems like you missed the ending `>` in the starting or ending tag of the property.